# API Calls Bypassing Proxy

Tags: linux, proxy, rider, mitmproxy, jetbrains-rider

I'm trying to debug an api call I'm making to a Local API and I have setup a proxy (mitmproxy) to capture the requests, I have also set the proxy settings in Postman, my IDE and Fedora Network Settings and imported the required CA certificate from mitmproxy.The proxy seems to be working fine except that any API calls my code makes are not captured regardless of whether I run my code from the terminal or my IDE. I can see captured requests from other apps on my system as well as postman requests to the same API.

Proxy Tool is mitmproxy with mitmweb
IDE is Jetbrains Rider
My code is written in dotnet 6

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: Why do you need the proxy to debug a local API? Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on your settings (client, server, etc.)?

Comment: So by local I mean the server is on the LAN, basically there's a REST API running on a webserver on the LAN, I have no control over the API code on the webserver as it belongs to an off the shelf app that I'm trying to integrate with. I'm writing a client that calls the API in Blazor and I need to debug the API calls. I hope that helps!

Comment: Usually, _local_ means _on my machine_  So, how have you configured your local code to use mitmproxy? Please add this information to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the proxy configuration in your machine.
In windows, proxy configuration, there is a checkbox that enables or disables the proxy for the local elements (localhosts). Try activating or desactivating this option.

Comment: How exactly is this done - Can you provide a reference for it?

Comment: If you press the windows key, and search for proxy, you can enter the Windows proxy configuration, and there you will have a check to enable or disable your proxy. Just try changening it and lets see if there is any change